Sidebar to stay collapsed when it refreshed
I am trying to create a sidebar with collapsible button.
When a button is clicked then the sidebar is collapsed, when the button is clicked again the sidebar will expand. This idea is already coded. Full code is here in fiddle
Now I want to make it stay collapsed when this button is clicked :
<i class="bx bx-menu toggle-sidebar"></i>

which will trigger the followings :
const toggleSidebar=document.querySelector('nav .toggle-sidebar');
const allSideDivider = document.querySelectorAll('#sidebar .divider');

if (sidebar.classList.contains('hide')){
    allSideDivider.forEach(item=>{
        item.textContent='-'
    })

    allDropdown.forEach(item=>{
        const a = item.parentElement.querySelector('a:first-child');
        a.classList.remove('active');
        item.classList.remove('show');
    })
    
}else{
    allSideDivider.forEach(item=>{
        item.textContent=item.dataset.text;
    })
}

toggleSidebar.addEventListener('click',function(){
    sidebar.classList.toggle('hide');
    if (sidebar.classList.contains('hide')){
        allSideDivider.forEach(item=>{
            item.textContent='-'
        })
        allDropdown.forEach(item=>{
            const a = item.parentElement.querySelector('a:first-child');
            a.classList.remove('active');
            item.classList.remove('show');
        })
    }else{
        allSideDivider.forEach(item=>{
            item.textContent=item.dataset.text;
        })
    }
})

and it stays collapsed when the page is refreshed (or open to other pages) until the button is clicked to expand.
Please advise if there is missing code I wrote or is there additional codes to write to aim the objective. Much appreciate.

In the third line of the JS code that you've posted here in your question, before the first if statement, add:
sidebar.classList.add('hide');

This will hide the sidebar by default when the page loads.

Hello @Rishikesh Negi, Thanks!
But, that is not what I want. The statement sidebar.classList.add('hide'); will make the sidebar collapsed as default. What I need is, if the hamburger button is clicked it will collapse the sidebar and stay collapsed until the button is clicked again, the collapsed/expand toggling is not affected by page refresh. Thank you.

So, you don't want the sidebar to expand when hovered over? Do you want to toggle it only using the hamburger button?

I want have it too: when mouse is hovered onto collapsed sidebar, it will expand

So, is this JS FIddle your code, or just an example of what you're trying to build?

Not an example, I am using this codes for my little project
